# Why is 2 of every 10 keystrokes in X11 missing?

Tags: input

When I enter 1234567890 two numbers in sequence are missing. E.g. 12567890 (missing 34).

What causes this?

Comment: Where do you enter those numbers, in the terminal?

Comment: Your typing skills need some work...

Comment: Trying to type more than two keys in **parallel** on a non-gaming keyboard ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by `ibus`. Killing `ibus-x11` fixes the problem.